# Understanding the logistic regression model from glmnet in R when the binary response is -1 or 1

Tags: logistic, binary-data, glmnet

I compared the results for the cases with y = {0,1} and y = {-1,1}. The estimated coefficients and probability from the method are different. How to understand these results?

```
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
head(mydata)
x = as.matrix(mydata[,-1])
y = mydata[,1]

# Model 
fit = cv.glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial")
pred = predict(fit,x,type="response")

# Model I
y1 = ifelse(y==0,-1,y)
fit1 = cv.glmnet(x, y1, family = "binomial")
pred1 = predict(fit1,x,type="response")

head(cbind(y, y1))
head(cbind(pred, pred1))
head(cbind(coef(fit), coef(fit1)))
```

The results are:

```
> head(cbind(y, y1))
     y y1
[1,] 0 -1
[2,] 1  1
[3,] 1  1
[4,] 1  1
[5,] 0 -1
[6,] 1  1
> head(cbind(pred, pred1))
             1         1
[1,] 0.2635955 0.2518074
[2,] 0.3084738 0.3107820
[3,] 0.4835674 0.5230911
[4,] 0.2285296 0.2151983
[5,] 0.2031040 0.1831863
[6,] 0.3510990 0.3560779
> head(cbind(coef(fit), coef(fit1)))
4 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                        1             1
(Intercept) -1.3306249789 -1.6569980680
gre          0.0007348088  0.0009755428
gpa          0.2392178325  0.3229661809
rank        -0.2798475240 -0.3228706721
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the output of the fit (by nature of the LASSO/ elastic net fitting procedure) is **random**. You can verify this yourself by running the code multiple times, when you do you should see different coefficients for the model every time you run it. You can also check that the results for both definitions of response are the same by setting the random seed to the same value before the fit command.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. After setting the same seed before each fit, the results are the same. Originally I thought it was related to the response format somehow.